# Горизонтальный скроллинг

Tags: javascript, html, php, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, на каком языке и как можно сделать, чтобы на сайте, при крокрутке колесом мыши, скролилось именно по горизонтали, а не по вертикали?

Comment: Да. Javascript

Comment: Для горизонтального скроллинга продаются мыши с двумя "колесиками". Не занимайтесь развратом - широкие страницы никто не любит, впрочем как и нестандартные реакции на стандартные действия. 

Ну а если уж очень надо, вот тут http://www.noinimod.ru/52/ есть статейка на близкую тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработчик на колесо и крутите на здоровье.

```
document.addEventListener('mousewheel', onWheel, false);
function onWheel(event) {
  window.scrollBy(event.wheelDelta, 0);
}
```

PS между прочим, широкие страницы - новый трэнд